# nouislider Handle null value for max Range

Tags: nouislider

How can we handle null value for max range in nouislider, below config I tried
config = {step  : 1,
range : {
min : 0,
max : null
}
}
It gives below error.
noUiSlider (14.1.1): 'range' contains invalid value.
In one of the scenarios I have to handle null value

Comment: It depends; What do you want to happen when you have no max value?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.